# Code Contracts: Require an IEnumerable to be non-empty

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, code-contracts

I have the following code:

```
public static IEnumerable<long> GetAllCombinations(IEnumerable<long> elements)
{
    Contract.Requires(elements != null);
    return GetAllCombinations(elements.ToList(), 0);
}
```

Static analysis now tells me to add another precondition:

> CodeContracts: Suggested precondition:
>   Contract.Requires(maximum >= 0)

I don't understand the suggestion because

a) If I already ensure that *elements* is not null, why should I check if its count is greater or ***equal*** to zero? I mean, passing a non-null value already means that it contains atleast zero elements?

b) How am I supposed to check the count (or maximum, as suggested) of an IEnumerable? The only way I see is to assign `elements.ToList()` to an extra variable and check that variable. But what, if I don't ever want to make a list out of the IEnumerable?

Leaves me confused.

**EDIT:**

I know all the extension methods for `IEnumerable<T>` and am well aware of `.Any()`, `.Count()`  etc.

What puzzles me is the message from static analyzer. Can anyone explain why it states `Contract.Requires(maximum >= 0)`?

Does it even mean what I think it means (checking for count of elements >= 0)?

And, as mentioned in a comment, why is the static analyzer still not happy with `Contract.Requires(elements.Any());`?

Comment: `elements.Any()` will fail if elements is null. This may be your problem.

Comment: @Aren: I still have the first check for null, so that's not the problem.

Comment: The static analyzer's Heuristic analysis may not be smart enough to chain your contracts. I was just stating a common point people miss about `IEnumerable<T>`'s Implementation. Try `Contract.Requires(elements != null && elements.Any())` and see if the warning goes away.

Comment: I'm thinking you're looking at the wrong method. When CodeContracts says "maximum >= 0" it's talking about an argument which doesn't exist here. Is it possible CodeContracts is giving bad 'links' from the output to the methods?

Comment: @Porges: I'm beginning to think the same. As if the static analyzer digs into the framework source and points me to some variable within the implementation of `Enumerable.ToList()`. I need to verify that this evening.

Comment: Is it possible that the static checker is referring to a parameter in your GetAllCombinations(IEnumerable<long>, int) method?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why static analysis suggests checking the count of the collection.  If an empty collection is passed, the code that evaluates it will not execute (i.e. a `foreach` statement), which should be o.k.  Perhaps this has something to do with the `Count` of a collection being a signed type?  You may want to try to satisfy the static analyzer with something like `Contracts.Assume(elements.Any())` or a statement that states the count is non-negative.

To address your second question, there are many ways to determine if an `IEnumerable<>` structure is non-empty.  To list a few, enabled by the `System.Linq` namespace:

- `elements.Any()`    // Checks for the presence of at least one element, O(1).
- `elements.Count()`  // Counts all the elements, O(n)
- `elements.Single()` // Raises an exception if more than one element exists, O(1).
- `elements.First()`  // Returns the first element, or raises an exception if empty, O(1).

The following two variations are equivalent to elements.Any(), where T is the type of the element in the container:

- `elements.SingleOrDefault() != default(T)`
- `elements.FirstOrDefault() != default(T)`

Comment: `Contract.Requires(elements.Any());` gives the same suggestion from the static analyzer.

Answer (score 0):

`elements.Count<long>()` will get you the count for an `IEnumerable<long>`.  You still want to check the count, as some methods will throw an exception on an empty IEnumerable (Single<>, for example).

Comment: Keep in mind that `Count()` *will* end up running over the whole IEnumerable - which could be expensive. If you just want to check whether an IEnumerable is empty or not, instead use the `Any()` method.

Comment: Very true.  I forgot about Any()

Answer (score -1):

> I mean, passing a non-null value
>   already means that it contains atleast
>   zero elements?

No. Quite some API#s returning an IEnumerable do acutally return something all the time - just empty.

> How am I supposed to check the count
>   (or maximum, as suggested) of an
>   IEnumerable?

THAT is the real problem actually. An Enumerable has no API for that.

Comment: An empty IEnumerable still has zero elements?

Comment: @VVS, yes Enumerable.Empty<long>() could have been passed in which it would not contain any elements.

Comment: @Gary: Yes, I already know that the IEnumerable could have zero or more elements. That's why I wonder why Code Contracts wants me to explicitly check for this condition. Read my argument again.

Comment: @VVS, sorry I was answering this: "An empty IEnumerable still has zero elements?"

Comment: @Gary: Ah, that was more of a statement than a question.